# Can anyone name this method for teaching children numbers and basic arithmetic? 

Tags: teaching, learning, math

I've heard about a method that uses the unstructured presentation of dots to teach younger kids numbers and basic arithmetic. Can anyone tell me the name of this method?

Or if you know of other interesting, more intuitive approaches to this kind of learning, please share.

Comment: I don't see that this is related to _parenting._ You might want to check out [this proposal about teaching](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23685/pedagogy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean Glenn Doman's [Dot Method](http://www.childandme.com/how-teach-your-child-math-glenn-domans-dot-method/)?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are referring to Touch Math. If so, here is a link with more info. http://www.touchmath.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=WYT.welcome&page=AboutTouchMath

Comment: Hmm, no - what I meant by unstructured is that the dots are arranged in random and I unrepeating positions (as opposed to on the numbers as with touch math or in set arrangements as with the pips on dice).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the touch math link, btw - that is how I learned (though I'm not sure I would recommend it)